# Excel formula where if Sheet1 Column A equal Sheet2 Column A AND Sheet1 Column B equals Sheet2 Column B, then copy certain data from Sheet2 to Sheet 1

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

What I want is if Location and Case Number line up on Sheet1 and Sheet2, add in the Attorney information from Sheet2 to Sheet1. Here's a sample of the kind of data I'm dealing with:

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xQOu.png)

We have repeated case numbers in multiple locations, so the data needs to match case number and location before inputting attorney names.

I stupidly deleted my previous attempts before thinking to ask for help, but I got pretty much every error in the book (#spill, #N/A, #ERROR, etc) I kept getting errors for VLOOKUP, and then I tried IFS, and still can't get anything to work.

My most recent attempt is:
[Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pa6X.png)

```
=IFS((A:A=Attorneys!A:A)AND(Sheet1!B:B=Attorneys!B:B), Attorneys!F:F)
```

Which resulted in #SPILL!

Then:
[Adjusted Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skVdG.png)

```
=@IFS((@A:A=@Attorneys!A:A)*AND(@Sheet1!B:B=@Attorneys!B:B),Attorneys!F:F)
```

Which resulted in most #N/A, but some random rows populated with one attorney's name, but none of the others.

I've done something similar before, but I was only trying to verify one column of data, not two, and that seems to be breaking my brain. I know I'm missing something really simple in here, but I just can't see it.

Edit:
I also tried Index because I forgot about that one, but I'm 99% sure I did it very incorrectly.

```
=INDEX(Attorneys!F:F,MATCH(A1&B1,Attorneys!A:A&Attorneys!B:B, 0))
```

And I got #N/A with no helpful information on the calculation error. This is the error I got: [Index Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv0Zd.png)

Edit 2: I had a stray comma which was causing the error on the Index! I still have some random entries where it's #N/A instead of a name, and I need to check to verify that the data is populating correctly instead of just putting in a random name.

Final edit:
Index without typos did it!

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!F:F,MATCH(A2&B2,Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B,0))
```

Comment: So, what's expected outcome if what value is used? Also please post data as data, not screenshot

Comment: If Location and Case Number Match, then it should input the attorney's name.

Also, sorry! I can't post the actual data, but I can post my made up data if that's easier?

Answer (score 3):

Try `index/match` like:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$4,MATCH(A7,IF($B$2:$B$4=B7,$A$2:$A$4),0))
```

[image]

Comment: I did something similar with ```=INDEX(Attorneys!F:F, MATCH(A1&B1, Attorneys!A:A&Attorneys!B:B, 0))``` but only got #N/A. Location is Column A on both sheets and Case Number is Column B on both sheets,  and the Attorney names in Columns F, G, H, I, and J on Sheet Attorney! and going to populate columns R, S, T, U, and V on Sheet1 (but I only wrote it to attempt to fill data from Attorneys!F to Sheet1!R

Comment: You should be able to modify the formula for two sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to u/findwindow, this is solved!

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!F:F,MATCH(A2&B2,Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B,0))
```

In my case, Sheet2 is called Attorneys, and I have headers so I skipped all of row 1.

Comment: If the answer provided with u/findwindow was correct, consider marking it as the accepted answer with the green checkmark.