# Use index in excel for multiple columns and criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, multi-index

I want to make a project priority Effort-Impact matrix.

The matrix has IMPACT - Low, Medium and High on X-axis AND
Effort - Low, Medium and High on Y-axis.

I have below rows in template where in "Task" column Project names would come and In Effort and Impact, I will choose per data validation.

[image: Table is like this]

[image: Template]

And choice combinations can be
Low Low,
Low Medium,
Low High,
Medium Low,
Medium Medium,
Medium High,
High Low,
High Medium,
High High

I want a formula which if I put in matrix, it will pull name of the project based on Effort and Impact combination.

I have below but it is working only for Low/High, not medium.

=IFERROR(INDEX($C$8:$C$47,SMALL(IF((LEN($C$8:$C$47)<>0)*($D$8:$D$47="High")*($E$8:$E$47="Low"),ROW($C$8:$C$47)-ROW($C$7),""),ROW(C8)-ROW($C$7))),"")

Please help.

Comment: Try `index/match` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808082/excel-formula-where-if-sheet1-column-a-equal-sheet2-column-a-and-sheet1-column-b/72808189#72808189)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(A7,IF($C$2:$C$5=B7,$B$2:$B$5),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, added snapshot of my table, pls see, need project name in buckets per impact and effort chosen.